# refresh form1 gridview from form2 after inserting the rows

Tags: c#

I have small issue, I have datagridview in form1 to which I insert data from form2 using SQL commands, but after button click which includes INSERT command the newly inserted value doesn't appear in form1's datagridview. Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Please give us some code...

Comment: Show us the code. I recommend using DataSource

Comment: In form2                                                      public Applications Applications;                              private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          String sSql = "INSERT INTO Application----
                    setup.SetQuery(sSql);
                }
                this.Close();
                Applications.Refresh();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: plz sent any sample codings links.

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Answer (score 0):

ftry this

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.methodwhereyoubindgrid();
```

but the method must be public in the form1

Comment: I tried Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.dgvappln.Refresh(); but it shows error "dgvappln is inaccessible due to protection level"

Comment: as i told you to make it public dear

Answer (score 0):

Just Rebind the data to the girdview after every insert.

```
gridview.DataSource=new Datasource;
gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.dgvappln.Refresh(); but it shows error "dgvappln is inaccessible due to protection level"

Comment: check if this could help http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/181697-how-to-access-controls-of-another-form/

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the GridView Bind Again at Button Click

inside `button1_click`

```
Grid1_Databind();
```

---

Rebind the data to the `gridview` after every insert.

```
gridview1.DataSource = new Datasource;
gridview1.DataBind();
```